# EF Core Update Linked Object

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.0

I am trying to update a company and its contact details as in the example JSON request using EF Core

```
PUT https://localhost:6001/api/Company

{
  "CompanyId": 6,
  "Name": "string",
  "ContactDetail": {
    "Name": "string",
    "EmailAddress": "string",
    "Address1": "string",
    "Address2": "string",
    "Address3": "string",
    "PostCode": "string",
    "Telephone": "string"
  }
}
```

The generated EF Scaffold looks like this

```
public partial class Company
{
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactDetail ContactDetail { get; set; }
}

public partial class ContactDetail
{
    public ContactDetail()
    {
        Company = new HashSet<Company>();
    }

    public long ContactDetailId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Company { get; set; }
}
```

How can I update the ContactDetail in the cleanest way possible, if I was to provide the ContactDetailId then I presume it would all work fine, but ideally I only want to provide the CompanyId of the parent object. 
The following code updates the Company but creates a new entry for the ContactDetail!?

```
  public Copmany Update(Copmany company)
  { 
      _bigLoaderContext.Update(company);
      _bigLoaderContext.SaveChanges();

      return GetById(company.CompanyId);
  }
```

Update - A solution I have now used is to get the ContactDetail id and then reassign it to the object.

```
public Company Update(Company company)
{
    var currentCompany = GetById(companyId, true);

    // Update the contact detail id so that it know what one to update
    company.ContactDetail.ContactDetailId = currentCompany.ContactDetailId;

    _bigLoaderContext.Update(company);
    _bigLoaderContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I was getting an error loading the object to get the value, so had to get it with the **AsNoTracking** in the GetById method.

```
_bigLoaderContext.Company.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(f => f.CompanyId == companyId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I have now used is to get the ContactDetail id and then reassign it to the object.

```
public Company Update(Company company)
{
    var currentCompany = GetById(companyId, true);

    // Update the contact detail id so that it know what one to update
    company.ContactDetail.ContactDetailId = currentCompany.ContactDetailId;

    _bigLoaderContext.Update(company);
    _bigLoaderContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I was getting an error loading the object to get the value, so had to get it with the AsNoTracking in the GetById method.

```
_bigLoaderContext.Company.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(f => f.CompanyId == companyId);
```

Presume this is ok as it works!?